How do I force Keycloak to encrypt JWT Access Token?
I am trying to make keycloak encrypting my JWT token. I cannot find any info about it. I have keycloak 22 and 25, no difference.
In Realm Settings > Token there is no section related to token encryption.
In Clients > My Client > Advanced I can choose signature algorithm for access token and it works, but there is no option for encrypting content of access token.
Any ideas?

For that the keycloak needs to know your client's public key. I think you have to register that key in the Client's menu.
Be aware, that an encryped JWT can still be (misused) by any malicious clients. Encrypting JWTs servers mostly the purpose of confidentiality.
